# How to use custom es6 Symbols in a type definition file, or: How to define a filter method for ES6 Set

Tags: typescript, symbols, typescript-typings, type-definition

I want to add a `filter` method to the es6 Set using a symbol. The method should work analogue to Array.prototype.filter . I do not know how to write the type definition file for that. This does not work in the .d.ts file:

```
const filterSymbol = Symbol()

interface Set {
  [filterSymbol]: any
}
```

The error I get is that filterSymbol cannot be assigned to a Symbol.

```
Error:(1, 19) TS1254: A 'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric literal.
```

I want to create this typing in order to have Set.prototype[filterSymbol] as part of my local standard library. So it is like an addition to lib.es6.d.ts .

Ofcourse, the implementation of the method will be:

```
Object.defineProperties(Set.prototype, {
  [ filterSymbol ]: {
    value: function <T> (this: Set<T>, f: (element: T) => boolean): Set<T> {
      return new Set([ ...this ].filter(f))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want.

Comment: What version of typescript do you use? Works fine in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)

Comment: @AlekseyL. In the playground you use a normal .ts file. I am talking about the typings file : .d.ts .

Comment: @MarcodeWit Then the question should state this explicitly. And here comes the problem. You can't have `const filterSymbol = Symbol()` in .d.ts.

Comment: Does it then mean that the only Symbol instances I can use in a .d.ts file are the predefined (e.g. Symbol.iterator) ones?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `declare` and the Typescript 2.7 feature `unique symbol` :

```
declare const filterSymbol = unique symbol

interface Set {
  [filterSymbol]: any
}
```